# Find Sequences of any ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, number-sequence

I need to find number sequence ranges in below number list. there are diffent number serials in the  list

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ocZtUeaKuvq9WMMP-QKbvhsQzZJ7SqYDOLH9acoBVa0/edit?usp=sharing

pls assist to find a foumular or rangers

sample

Start Number     -  End number

9402970201041150 - 9402970201041239

tks
isuru

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

see:

```
=INDEX("9402970"&SEQUENCE(C2-C1, 1, 
 REGEXEXTRACT(TEXT(C1, "0")&"", "\d{9}$")*1))
```

[image]